# Azure Virtual Machine (Ubuntu) how to deploy multiple Python websites

Tags: python, django, azure, virtual-machine

I am new to Python / Azure VM world.

1. I have created Python/Django website using PyCharm IDE.
2. Created Azure VM with Python/Django installed
3. on Azure VM , I can run : Python manage.py runserver and i can access it using Azure URL from externally.

Question:

1. to run/deploy a python website on VM, do we have to run Python manage.py command or there is any other way ?
2. in case I have to deploy multiple websites what i should do ?
3. and python manage.py session also gets expired pretty soon and site is not accessible anymore , how to keep it running ?

Regards Shakeel

Comment: Did you think about better hosting these multiple web sites with App Service instead of an Azure VM? : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=bash&pivots=python-framework-flask

Answer (score 0):

after some research I found the solution, answer to my own question is for my requirements I can use NGINX and GUNICORN :)

Comment: Good research and good that you found the answer, but I would still recommend checking out @Kai Walter's comment on your original question. If at all possible, the service apps might save you some money on operational costs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).